# VS Code Unable to start terminal process: CreateProcess failed

Tags: visual-studio-code, sapui5, sap-fiori

I am trying to open Terminal window in VS Code and it fails with message

> Unable to start terminal process: CreateProcess failed

I saw this link with same issue but not how he fixed it. Any ideas?
https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/57285

My **`settings.json`**:

```json
{
  "[xml]": {
    "editor.defaultFormatter": "SAPSE.sap-ux-annotation-modeler-extension"
  },
  "ui5.plugin.jsCodeLens": true,
  "ui5.plugin.ui5version": "1.71.22",
  "sap.ux.serviceModeler.selectDefaultView": "Expanded",
  "workbench.editorAssociations": [],
  "terminal.integrated.windowsEnableConpty": false
}
```

This is the powershell config file:

```xml
<configuration>
  <uri>
    <schemeSettings>
      <add name="http" genericUriParserOptions="DontUnescapePathDotsAndSlashes" />
      <add name="https" genericUriParserOptions="DontUnescapePathDotsAndSlashes" />
    </schemeSettings>
  </uri>
  <runtime>
    <AppContextSwitchOverrides value="Switch.System.Net.DontEnableSystemDefaultTlsVersions=false" />
  </runtime>
</configuration>
```

Not sure exactly what to do...

Comment: Well he explained his fix in the last response to the issue.

Answer (score 10):

I could fix with below line of code in settings.json

https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/66894

```
"terminal.integrated.shell.windows": "C:\\WINDOWS\\System32\\cmd.exe"
```

Answer (score -1):

When I started my terminal, it was not working. I got an error like this:

[image]

Then I opened settings.json and removed the entire code and opened https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/integrated-terminal. Copy the link for powershell:

```json
"terminal.integrated.profiles.windows": {
  "PowerShell -NoProfile": {
    "source": "PowerShell",
    "args": ["-NoProfile"]
  }
},
```

If you want to link Git bash then

1. Install git
2. Copy the link of your git directory

   - My directory is: "C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\bin\bash"
3. Paste it like this

   ```json
   "terminal.integrated.profiles.windows": {
     "PowerShell -NoProfile": {
       "source": "PowerShell",
       "args": ["-NoProfile"]
     }
       "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Git\\bin\\bash"
   },
   ```

Close the window and now restart VS Code. Then you will able to open the terminal.

Comment: Please make sure to format your posts properly so that it is readable. I fixed it for you now, but for your future posts, learn more about Stack Overflow's formatting here: https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting.